# Suggestion for new vga Card under ubuntu 16.04 and other linux distros?

Tags: vga

I need your help regarding my graphics on my PC. Ubuntu 16.04 still gives me some problems and I would love to think buying a VGA card since i am using my integrated one. I think this is the problem i face. Some tearing when scrolling Firefox - some images while browsing are lagging my UI a bit and overall i am not so happy. My PC specs are:

CPU : AMD A8 7600 (Kaveri APU 4 core) R7 graphics, I am using those

SSD : Crucial brand new 275GB

M/B : MSI A88XM - E35

RAM : 6GB DDR3 1600MHZ (4GB + 2GB) Dimms

PSU : Usual 500 watt

I am aware that APU's were facing problems since 16.04 where out. Tried AMD GPU-Pro 16.60 drivers same issues.

I use my machine mainly for web developing like Wordpress etc. No gaming at the moment since I decided to abandon Windows once and for all. On Windows performance was OK.

Also I don't wanna go back to 14.04 since I've tried in the past and missed a lot of features. I think that buying a VGA card will solve my problems.

So the questions are:

1: NVIDIA vs AMD for me?

2: Which model should I prefer? Budget is around 70-80$.